# how to kill a command executed within xterm

Tags: ruby, linux, process, xterm

I'd like to control the execution of shell commands within an xterm window. 
This is an example code (Ruby):

```
pid = Process.fork
if pid.nil? 
  exec "xterm -e 'while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done'"
else
  puts "pid is: #{pid}"
  Process.detach(pid)
end
```

However, the xterm window doesn't get killed:

```
$ ./tst2.rb 
pid is: 26939
$ ps aux | grep xterm | grep -v grep
user   26939  0.0  0.0   4508   800 pts/3    S    13:11   0:00 sh -c xterm -e 'while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done'
user   26943  0.6  0.0  72568  6280 pts/3    S    13:11   0:00 xterm -e while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done
$ kill 26939
$ ps aux | grep xterm | grep -v grep
user   26943  0.1  0.0  72568  6280 pts/3    S    13:11   0:00 xterm -e while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done
```

How can the xterm window be killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the PID of the xterm process in order to kill it. In your case, the easiest way would be to bypass the `sh` process, as you don't need it. To do this, you have to pass the arguments to `exec` in an array, not as a command line:

```
exec('xterm', '-e', 'while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done')
```